# Assigning arrow function to generic function type with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

I've done some digging on similar questions but I cannot find a solution that works. I've got some types of generic functions, but I cannot seem to implement them correctly.

In short, I have this:

```
/** Takes three values of the same type and collapses them into one */
declare type MergeFunction = <T>(def: T, file?: T, arg?: T) => T

/** The implementation I'm having trouble with. Merge three arrays of the same type. */
const arrayMerge: MergeFunction = <T>(def: T[], file: T[] = [], arg: T[] = []): T[] => [ ].concat(def).concat(file || [ ]).concat(arg || [ ])
```

However, I get a compiler error:

```
Property 'arrayMerge' is incompatible with index signature.
  Type '<A>(def: A[], file?: A[], arg?: A[]) => A[]' is not assignable to type 'MergeFunction'.
    Types of parameters 'def' and 'def' are incompatible.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type '{}[]'.
```

How do I actually implement this type?

Comment: Not sure what you want to enforce here, just that all 3 arguments are of the same type ? What type safety are you looking for from `MergeFunction` ?

Comment: There are multiple instances of these `MergeFunction`s. One takes three strings and returns a string, one takes three numbers and returns a number, etc. However, when passed around, it's generalized as a `MergeFunction`, not its implementation. The goal here was to be able to pass this general type around, and it would still work the same regardless of how it acted underneath. That is, `merge(1,2,3)` returns a `number` while `merge('foo','bar','baz')` returns a `string`, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you've defined it, a function of type `MergeFunction` must work for *any* type `T` that the *caller* specifies.  So `arrayMerge` is *not* a `MergeFunction`, since it only accepts arrays.  Here's one way to implement your `MergeFunction` as specified:

```
declare type MergeFunction = <T>(def: T, file?: T, arg?: T) => T;
const returnLastSpecifiedThing: MergeFunction = <T>(def: T, file?: T, arg?: T) =>
  typeof arg !== 'undefined' ? arg : 
  typeof file !== 'undefined' ? file : 
  def;
```

In fact, the only thing you can safely do when implementing a type like `MergeFunction` is to return one of the inputs, because [you don't know anything about `T`](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/09/22/parametricity-money-for-nothing-and-theorems-for-free/) since the caller is in charge of that.  There's certainly no way to be sure that `T` is an array.

---

Perhaps you mean for `MergeFunction` to be a type where the *implementer* chooses the generic parameter `T`.  In this case, you can make the *type* generic instead of the *function*:

```
declare type MergeFunction<T> = (def: T, file?: T, arg?: T) => T;
```

Note how the `<T>` moved from the function to the type.  The original definition is a *specific type alias* which refers to a *generic function type*, while the new definition is a *generic type alias* which, when you plug in a value for `T`, refers to a *specific function type*.  (Sorry if that's confusing.)  It is now much easier to implement *some* specific type of this.  For example:

```
const concatenateStrings: MergeFunction<string> = 
  (def: string, file?: string, arg?: string) =>
    def + (file ? file : "") + (arg ? arg: "");
```

The function `concatenateStrings` is a `MergeFunction<string>`.

At this point it seems like it should be simple to represent `arrayMerge` as some kind of `MergeFunction<>`.  Unfortunately it isn't.  TypeScript lacks [the sort of generics](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) you need here.  What you *want* to say is something like:

```
const arrayMerge: <T> MergeFunction<T[]> = // invalid syntax
  (def: T[], file: T[] = [], arg: T[] = []): T[] =>
    ([] as T[]).concat(def).concat(file || []).concat(arg || []);
```

But you can't do that directly (as the linked issue describes).  The closest you can get is to add a layer of indirection, such as a function call:

```
const makeArrayMerge = <T>(): MergeFunction<T[]> =>
  (def: T[], file: T[] = [], arg: T[] = []): T[] =>
    ([] as T[]).concat(def).concat(file || []).concat(arg || []);
```

Now `makeArrayMerge` is a function that, when called with a specified type parameter `T`, *produces* a `MergeFunction<T>`.  This works, but is harder to use (and doesn't infer types the way you'd like):

```
const numArray = makeArrayMerge<number>()([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]);
```

Oh well, that's the best I can do given the limitations of TypeScript generics.  It's up to you to decide if you really need the above indirection or if some specific array type will work for you.  Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!