# Generic constraint when defining a type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to come up with a type for a function with a single callback parameter (also a function) such that the type of the parameter of that callback is restricted to *object* only.

However I am getting a type error. Here is the code:

```js
function aaa(a: { n: number }) { }

type Cb = <T extends object>(a: T) => void
function ccc(fn: Cb) { }
// type error - why?
ccc(aaa)
```

Type error:

```
Argument of type '(a: { n: number; }) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Fn'.
  Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type '{ n: number; }'.
      Type 'object' is not assignable to type '{ n: number; }'.
        Property 'n' is missing in type '{}'.
```

A similar generic constraint, but applied to a function definition, works fine:

```js
function aaa(a: { n: number }) { }

function bbb<T extends object>(fn: (a: T) => void) { }
// all good
bbb(aaa)
```

What is the difference between the two? And how can I get the former one to work?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20aaa(a%3A%20%7Bn%3A%20number%7D)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20bbb(fn%3A%20(a%3A%20object)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Abbb(aaa)) link

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933740/assigning-arrow-function-to-generic-function-type-with-typescript

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the regular function `aaa` is not compatible with the generic function signature `Cb`.

You probably want to declare `Cb` as a normal function signature, but with `Cb` having the generic type parameter

```
function aaa(a: { n: number }) { }

type Cb<T extends object> = (a: T) => void
function ccc<T extends object>(fn: Cb<T>) { }
// ok
ccc(aaa)
```