# Argument of type 'T' isn't assignable to parameter of type 'number'

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash, typescript-generics

I don't understand if `<T>` is a number in my case why is it not assignable to parameter of type number? If I change type of **`n`** to `number` or `any`(obviously) it'll work anyway.

**Error:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
const dropFoo = <T>(arr: T[], n: T): T[] => {
  return _.drop(arr, n)
};
const drop = dropFoo<number>([1, 2, 3], 1);
console.log(drop);
```

Comment: you are assigning `n` a type of `T` instead of `Number` in your function signature for `dropFoo`. its a simple fix, no?

Comment: The second argument in `drop` is an index. Is that what `n` is supposed to be? If so, is it possible for `T` to be something other than a number?

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933740/assigning-arrow-function-to-generic-function-type-with-typescript) explains it (the question is slightly different, but the explanation is basically the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `T` can be anything, not just a number. `drop` however expects its second argument to be always a number. You have to limit it to numbers only with `<T extends number>` and then the generic isn't useful at all (it generally isn't here).